# java.lang.VerifyError while starting spring boot app using tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, jvm, tomcat8

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:313] - Context initialization failed
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/springframework/core/type/StandardAnnotationMetadata, method: getAnnotationTypes signature: ()Ljava/util/Set;) Illegal type in constant pool
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata.introspect(AnnotationMetadata.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.dt_133_checkConfigurationClassCandidate_98(ConfigurationClassUtils.java)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4792)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is happeing in one of the deployment environment whereas it runs fine on other VM.
Both the VMs have same version of JDK, tomcat and spring versions.

I am not able to find any reason why this is happening. What could be the issue?

Comment: that's interesting. it complains that the expected return type of `StandardAnnotationMetadata::getAnnotationType`, which is `java.util.Set`, in invalid in the constant pool of the class file. It seems some code alters the byte-code and messes up the constant pool entries.

Comment: I thought re-installing JDK might fix this but I still see the same issue. I can install this in every other environment but this is a PROD VM so I'm not even able to do the RCA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my case the culprit was `Dynatrace`. At runtime `Dynatrace` performs some instrumentation in class files for monitoring performance which modifies the java class bytecode. Now, if dynatrace version in not compatible with installed `runtime JDK` we might end up seeing issues like:

```
warning [native] Error during parsing of java bytecode: Java classes with "invokedynamic" are not supported, skipping class transformation (class java/time/Instant)
```

OR

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:313] - Context initialization failed
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/springframework/core/type/StandardAnnotationMetadata, method: getAnnotationTypes signature: ()Ljava/util/Set;) Illegal type in constant pool
    at
```

After disabling `Dynatrace` and re-installing app & JDK everything worked fine. This is one of the issues that can be observed is such scenarios.